# Improve code with Factory Pattern and DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, refactoring, factory-pattern

I am looking on ways to improve the following code:

```
public interface IExample{ void Do(); }

public interface IExampleA: IExample {}

public class ExampleA: IExampleA { public void Do(); }

public interface IExampleB: IExample {}

public class ExampleB: IExampleB { public void Do(); }

public interface IExampleFactory{
    IExample Make(TypesOfExamples thisIsAnEnum);
}

public class ExampleFactory: IExampleFactory {
    IExampleA _exampleA;
    IExampleB _exampleB;

    public ExampleFactory(IExampleA exampleA, IExampleB exampleB)
    {
        _exampleA = exampleA;
        _exampleB = exampleB;
    }

    public IExample Make(TypesOfExamples thisIsAnEnum)
    {
        switch(thisIsAnEnum)
        {
            case A: return _exampleA;
            case B: return _exampleB;
        }
    }        
}
```

Basically what I don't like is having to use the IExampleA and IExampleB, they are there only for being injected:

```
container.Bind<IExampleA>().To.<ExampleA>();
container.Bind<IExampleB>().To.<ExampleB>();
container.Bind<IExampleFactory>().To.<ExampleFactory>();
```

And it would be used like this

```
public class ExampleUsage()
{    
    ExampleFactory _exampleFactory;

    public ExampleUsage(ExampleFactory exampleFactory)
    {
        _exampleFactory = exampleFactory;
    }

    public void useFactory(Test obj)
    {
        var implementation = _exampleFactory.Make(obj.ThisIsAnEnum);
        implementation.Do();
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit I had forgotten to mention that both ExampleA and ExampleB has some dependencies that need to be taken care of by the DI

```
public class ExampleA: IExampleA 
{ 
    IDependencyA _dependencyA;
    IDependencyB _dependencyB;

    public ExampleA(IDependencyA dependencyA, IDependencyB dependencyB)
    {
        _dependencyA = dependencyA;
        _dependencyB = dependencyB;
    }

    public void Do(); 
}

public class ExampleB: IExampleB 
{ 
    IDependencyA _dependencyA;
    IDependencyB _dependencyB;
    IDependencyC _dependencyC;

    public ExampleA(IDependencyA dependencyA, IDependencyB dependencyB, IDependencyC dependencyC)
    {
        _dependencyA = dependencyA;
        _dependencyB = dependencyB;
        _dependencyC = dependencyC;
    }
    public void Do(); 
}

container.Bind<IDependencyA>().To.<DependencyA>();
container.Bind<IDependencyB>().To.<DependencyB>();
container.Bind<IDependencyC>().To.<DependencyC>();
```

Comment: Use http://codereview.stackexchange.com for questions about improving code

Comment: thanks! @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: created this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158733/advide-on-factory-pattern-with-di-implementation

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong with the Factory.

There is no point to inject ExampleA and ExampleB to the Factory.

Since the factory pattern is responsible for creation, therefore you can do instantiation from inside factory class.

This could be easy to replace the factory with the other implementations of the IExampleFactory.

*Edited added more details.

Actually the DI container can be considered as a factory (both are responsible for objects creation).

But if you want to go the factory way, you can implement you own instantiation logic.

Of course, you need to handle the dependencies by the factory.

The factory interface is better to define the objects to be created separately.

```
public interface IExampleFactory
{
    IExampleA CreateExampleA();
    IExampleB CreateExampleB();
}
```

Then the concrete factory should handle the instantiation process of each object.

you can do anything to get all dependencies to instantiate the object (each object can have different dependencies).

```
public class ExampleFactory: IExampleFactory 
{
    IExampleA CreateExampleA()
    {
        //instantiating concrete object A with its dependencies

        return concreteA;
    }

    IExampleB CreateExampleB();
    {
        //instantiating concrete object B with its dependencies

        return concreteB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah you are right, Im looking for ways to change my factory to return a concrete implementation, my only problem with that, (and I did not put that in the example, Ill add it in a sec), is that the ExampleA and ExampleB classes has lots of dependencies that are managed by the DI, if I were to return the concrete class I would have to manage the dependencies myself